# Filter out rows that have a computed column value of null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query something along the lines of:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(month, titlStreaming)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(day, titlStreaming)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, titlStreaming)) AS [Day], 
COUNT(titlTitleID) AS Total 
FROM Title
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, titlStreaming), DATEPART(month, titlStreaming), DATEPART(day, titlStreaming)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, titlStreaming) DESC, DATEPART(month, titlStreaming) DESC, DATEPART(day, titlStreaming) DESC
```

That generally returns a table like:

```
Day       |   Total
--------------------
4/23/2013 |       2
         ...
NULL      |   14234
```

What I would like to do is filter out the row that has a `NULL` value from returning.
Because `Day` is a computed column obviously I cannot simply do a `WHERE Day IS NOT NULL`.
I'll admit my knowledge of SQL is quiet lacking so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nathan, if you get an answer that fixes your problem, don't forget to green check it. We like to help, but we also like reputation points :)

Comment: Yeah, just have to wait on that 10 min time limit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as all dateparts depend on titlStreaming a where condition on titlStreaming should be enough.

```
....
From Title
where titlStreaming is not null
Group by ....
```

Comment: Wow.  Now I feel dumb for asking.  That's incredibly simple and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(month, titlStreaming)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(day, titlStreaming)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, titlStreaming)) AS [Day], 
             COUNT(titlTitleID) AS Total 
     FROM Title
     GROUP BY DATEPART(year, titlStreaming), DATEPART(month, titlStreaming), DATEPART(day, titlStreaming)
    ) t
where [day] is not null
ORDER BY [day] DESC
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, however when I add `HAVING [Day] IS NOT NULL` I get `Invalid column name 'Day'.`

Comment: @NathanR . . . I was originally confused on the database. The subquery or bummi's solution is fine.